# Clarification for the anatomical terminology of the cerebellum

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology, neuroanatomy

I've been trying to find descriptions for some of the fissures found on the inferior surface of the cerebellum, and so far the only source I've been able to find that provides an adequate description is Gray's anatomy (1918, 20th edition):

> The prepyramidal fissure crosses the vermis between the uvula in front and the pyramid behind, then curves forward between the tonsil and the biventral lobe, to join the postnodular fissure.
> The postpyramidal fissure passes across the vermis between the pyramid and the tuber vermis, and, in the hemispheres, courses behind the tonsil and biventral lobules, and then along the lateral border of the
> biventral lobule to the postnodular sulcus; in the hemisphere it forms the anterior boundary of the inferior semilunar lobule.

So, that would make these fissures the following ones:
[image]

(the blue one being the postpyramidal fissure, and the red one being the prepyramidal fissure)

However, I checked a few atlases:
[image]

(here, 2 and 2' are the postpyramidal fissure and 4 is the prepyramidal fissure)

And on radiologykey, the descriptions it gives for these fissures is the following:

1. The postpyramidal (secondary) fissure separates the pyramis/biventral lobule above from the uvula/tonsils below
2. the prepyramidal fissure separates the tuber above from the pyramis below.

It seems like Gray's anatomy has the names swapped or something, is that the case? If so, that means I can still use these descriptions but just swap the names.

And is the secondary fissure the same as the retrotonsilar fissure/postpyramidal fissure?